# TimerTask hangs

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am trying to launch a period task from main() via the TimerTask functionality in Java and the run() task is hanging. The code after the Timer is a REPL. The code looks like this:

```
public static void main( String[] asArguments ){
    java.util.Timer timer = new Timer();
    long durationDelay_ms = 60*60*1000; // 1 hour
    long durationPeriod_ms = 60*60*1000; // 1 hour
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(  // reload prices every hour
        new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringBuffer sbError = new StringBuffer();
                if( ! reload( false, sbError ) ){
                    System.out.println( "error reloading prices: " );
                }
                sbError = null; // garbage collect
            }
    }, durationDelay_ms, durationPeriod_ms );

    // REPL
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
    while( true ){
        System.out.print( "> " );
        try {
            String s = br.readLine();
            \\ ... code to process command
        } catch( Throwable t ) {
            \\ handle error 
        }
    }
}

public static final boolean reload( ){
    for( int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ){
        String sURL = "c:\\xyz.com\\" + i; \\ URL I am reading from
        System.out.println( "retrieving data from:\n" + sURL );
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( 10000 );
        try {
            URL url = new URL( sURL );
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            sb = readStream( con.getInputStream() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( sb.toString() );
}
```

The task tries to make multiple URL connections and print out the response of each one. What happens in practice is that "retrieving data from..." message appears once, then the task appears to hang. If I use the the REPL, by typing a command at StdIn, then "connection timed out" errors appear in stdout.

So, the TimerTask seems to be conflicting with the REPL (which is blocking on readline) somehow. What is going here?

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) has only thread to run task. If one task keep running, other tasks have to wait util it finished.
You can replace it with [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), it could launch more thread to run task...

I guess the URL that you try to connect required some "input", so it's waiting for extra data... 
Try to modify the source code and give it some data. For example:

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);//not required
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
    out.write("&param1=a&param2=b".getBytes());
    out.close();
    sb = readStream( con.getInputStream() );
```

Comment: There is no issue with task overlap here. The period of the timer is 1 hour, so no task conflict is occurring. The FIRST task that runs is being hung somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out the problem. The HttpURLConnection openConnection method implementations synchronize on an internal object called `streamHandlerLock` which is shared by a bunch of different internal Java libraries including the buffered reading libraries.

What this basically means is that you cannot use any stream-based IO using java.net or java.io in multiple concurrent threads.

In my case what is happening is the REPL is blocking on `BufferedReader.readLine()` so the `streamHandlerLock` is frozen. So, when openConnection executes it deadlocks on this object.

*(I could say something here about the coding skills of James Gosling who designed and wrote this borked up system and signed his name to the source code, or I could say something about the complete failure of the Sun Oak team to rewrite this garbage when Java went mainstream in 2000, 16 years ago, but I guess I will leave it to the readers imagination what I might say.)*